# npm install error web project

Tags: node.js, npm

When I try install npm modules I see the following problem:

```
PS C:\Users\maxzag\Desktop\svoi> npm install
npm ERR! Cannot read property '0' of undefined

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\maxzag\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-08-15T11_25_41_473Z-debug.log
```

Can someone already come across this problem and can something advise?

Comment: Do you have a `package.json` file? Can you include it in your question?

Comment: what npm version are you using ? try  `npm -v`

Comment: Thank you guys but have already solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be your issue: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17858

Try removing `node_modules` and running `npm install` again.